# How to make .htaccess strict in accepting parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am using the following .htaccess code for pretty URL.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)$ app/post.php?&category=$2&slug=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/([\w-]+)$ app/post.php?category=$2 [L]
```

From the above code I can achieve the following:

From this
`https://www.example.com/post.php?category=tech&slug=some-title`

to this `https://www.example.com/tech/some-title`

When I see parameters using `print_r($_GET)` for the URL `https://www.example.com/tech/some-title`

I can see `Array ( [category] => tech [slug] => some-title )`

but when I pass another argument like this `https://www.example.com/tech/some-title/78yi`

then I can see `Array ( [category] => some-title [slug] => 78yi )`

and so on if I go on adding it pushes the parameter as explained.

How to make it consistent. Irrespective to parameters. Like how many ever parameters someone puts it should only accept the first and second parameter.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your first capture group captures everything (.+) plus two remaining "words". If you want to capture the first two, you have to invert your 'catch all logic'. Something similar to https://regex101.com/r/paA8rX/1

Comment: @KasperAgg I'm not getting how to and where to alter the code

Comment: I'm still not 100% sure what you're tryin to achieve, but if you check the link, you can play around until you got what you need an replace the RewriteRule.